# Android Studio Cucumber for Java plugin

Tags: android, plugins, intellij-idea, android-studio, cucumber-jvm

I've been trying whole day to use Cucumber with Android Studio to test my android application but I am stuck at installing plugins.

I am following the procedure on jetbrains webhelp : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-cucumber-support-in-project.html and it states :

> ## Prerequisite
>
> > Note
> >
> > Make sure that Cucumber for Java and/or Cucumber for Groovy bundled plugins are enabled. The choice of plugin depends on the type of step definitions to be generated.

Currently, I am using Android Studio Beta 0.8.9 based on IntelliJ build 135.1404660. The only place I found the `Cucumber for Java` plugin was on `JetBrains Plugins Repository` (accessed from a browser, NOT via Android Studio, because it is not listed there). Here is the link : http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212?pr=androidstudio

The lastest version of the plugin (published on 2014-10-15 17:30:53 for IntelliJ build 139.69) is not compatible with the IntelliJ build Android Studio is currently using, so I installed the previous version (published on 2014-02-12 15:22:49 for IntelliJ build 134.1007) with `Install plugin from disk` via the `Plugins` page in the settings of Android Studio. Unfortunately, it pops the following warning :

> Plugin Cucumber for Java depends on unknown plugin cucumber

What is the cucumber plugin? Or is there another place I can get a working version of the Cucumber for Java plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unknown plugin cucumber is actually `Gherkin` and can be downloaded here : http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7211?pr=androidstudio